# Python bool compare vs string compare

Tags: python

This question is out of itch of being perfect.

I come across the case where I have to get parameter from post and check if it is `True` or `False` (in python), and accordingly call the LOC.

Obviously parameter read is of type `<str>` and `if param:` always return `True`.

I had two options now,
1. Convert `<str>` to `<bool>`  (write own code to convert, or use `ast.literal_eval` or import `from distutils.util import strtobool` )
2. Do the string comparison like `if param == "True":`

**The question is what would be the best practice to follow?**

Comment: Please Down voters explain the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would certainly not go down the route of converting the string to a boolean, that's too much overhead for a simple logic statement.
You should first ensure the parameter is either of the values 'True' or 'False'.

Then:

```
if (param == 'True'):
    # True code here
else:
    # False code here
```

Comment: You are right, the read `<str>` parameter has already taken the memory, and converting it to bool will add additional overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Memory Considerations:

```
For String
sys.getsizeof("True")
>> 41
sys.getsizeof("False")
>> 42

For Boolean
sys.getsizeof(True)
>> 24
sys.getsizeof(False)
>> 24
```

Comment: But then you have overhead of converting string to bool as said by @Adam Probert

Comment: I am checking  the runtime overhead of conversion.. Will post the results after running test.

Comment: Well you can use cprofile and check for the runtime difference in your program. Memory wise boolean takes lesser space.